# How to replace a column value in a CSV file with NA using python without pandas

Tags: python, csv

I need to replace all the column values that are empty with "NA" but the only condition that I have is not to use Pandas.
Can anyone help me?

I have looked for an answer all over

```
import csv

#Creates empty set - this will be used to store the values that have already been used
filelist = set()

#Opens the large csv file in "read" mode
with open('//directory/largefile', 'r') as csvfile:

#Read the first row of the large file and store the whole row as a string (headerstring)
read_rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
headerrow = next(read_rows)
headerstring=','.join(headerrow) 

for row in read_rows:

    #Store the whole row as a string (rowstring)
    rowstring=','.join(row)

    #Defines filename as the first entry in the row - This could be made dynamic so that the user inputs a column name to use
    filename = (row[0])

    #This basically makes sure it is not looking at the header row.
    if filename != "Category":

        #If the filename is not in the filelist set, add it to the list and create new csv file with header row.
        if filename not in filelist:    
            filelist.add(filename)
            with open('//directory/subfiles/' +str(filename)+'.csv','a') as f:
                f.write(headerstring)
                f.write("\n")
                f.close()    
        #If the filename is in the filelist set, append the current row to the existing csv file.     
        else:
            with open('//directory/subfiles/' +str(filename)+'.csv','a') as f:
                f.write(rowstring)
                f.write("\n")
                f.close()
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Do you want to replace NA values, or do you want to replace a non-NA value with NA? Please provide an example of what you want (and what you are getting now with your code).

Comment: i want to replace empty values with NA

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.